# Joining Tables in SQL and combine fields

Tags: sql, join

I have a couple of tables I would like to join.

The first holds details about a student and their classes they do.

[image]

Next, I have a table which only holds the results for the student in those classes.

[image]

How can I join these two tables so that it only returns the 7 rows in the second table but includes the other details from the first such as studenthouse etc? You can link the tables  using classcode but this removes the 11TOK/EE class

In the second table, the class (11CASIBC) is not used in the second table, while 11EEIB and 11TOKIBC are combined into 1 row in the second table (11TOK/EE) In the raw result column in the second table, TOK gained a score of 3 and EE scored a mark of 5. They are combined in a string which is 3|5. the final result for these 2 results is shown in the WeightedResult column and it is 2.00. It has combined the two rows into one row.

I have used a Left Outer Join for the two tables, including all rows from table 2 and get the following result.

[image]

It is close but does not include the 11TOK/EE class with its results. Here is the SQL I used.

```
SELECT b.FileYear, 
       b.FileSemester, 
       b.ClassCode, 
       b.StudentID, 
       b.StudentHouse,                                               
       b.StudentTutor, 
       a.RawResult, 
       a.WeightedResult
FROM   uStudentMerits a LEFT OUTER JOIN
       vStudentClassesAll b 
ON     a.FileYear = b.FileYear 
       AND a.FileSemester = b.FileSemester 
       AND a.ID = b.StudentID 
       AND a.ClassCode = b.ClassCode
WHERE  (b.FileYear = 2015) AND (b.FileSemester = 3) AND (b.StudentID = 43836)
```

How can I change this to include the 11TOK/EE class as the 7th row with all the other fields populated? Note: because the two classes are combined, the SchoolStaffCode for 11TOK/EE should always be the teacher of the 11TOKIBC class. Hope this makes sense. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Move b-table conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN!

Comment: use coalesce in on clause for ClassCode ( COALESCE(a.ClassCode,'a')=COALESCE(b.ClassCode,'a')

Answer (score 0):

Your join conditions aren't quite correct. You'll need to do the following to get the results you're after by forcing the join on the conditions you want to filter by:

```
  SELECT b.FileYear, 
           b.FileSemester, 
           b.ClassCode, 
           b.StudentID, 
           b.StudentHouse,                                               
           b.StudentTutor, 
           a.RawResult, 
           a.WeightedResult
    FROM   uStudentMerits AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
           vStudentClassesAll AS b 
    ON     a.FileYear = b.FileYear 
           AND a.FileSemester = b.FileSemester 
           AND a.ID = b.StudentID 
           AND a.ClassCode = b.ClassCode
           AND b.FileYear = 2015 
           AND b.FileSemester = 3 
           AND b.StudentID = 43836
```